Using the parametric form of a line for the poitns of intersection of a line and a curve

The line y= tan$(\phi)x$ cuts the curve $x^3 + xy^2 +2x^2+2y^2+3x+1=0$ at the points A,B and C.
If O is the origin, OA, OB, OC are in a HP. then tan$\phi$ is equal to?

For the given question, I assumed the distance of the points of intersection to be 'r'.
This gives the value of the point of intersection as  $(rcos\phi,rsin\phi)$.
Inputting these values of x, and y in the equation for the curve we obtain a cubic equation in r. Using the relationships between the coefficients of a cubic equation and its roots we further obtain 3 equations with $r_1,r_2,r_3$.
As the 3 solutions are in a HP we can write them as $r_1=\frac{1}{a-d},  r_2 = \frac{1}{a}, 
  r_3=\frac{1}{a+d}$.
However, doing this I obtain the value the $d^2$ as $-1/2$, which makes the roots of the cubic equation imaginary which is obviously wrong.
I am not able to understand the error in my approach.

Are you sure you got the equation of the curve right? When I plotted it, it seemed like a line through origin cannot intersect it at three points.

@Pranay, I had mistakenly put the coefficient of x as 2 instead of 3, but even then your point still stands. I had came across the question in one of my workbooks, so I think the question itself is wrong. Thank you for your help!

Okay, but even the new plot seems like there can’t be three solutions. Where did you find this question?
